# Typo3 powermail extension "ods_pm_ajax" not working

Tags: ajax, forms, typo3

I have installed in TYPO3 the extension ods_pm_ajax for ajax submit, but for some reason this doesnt seem to work. I get an error like in line 5 of ods_pm_ajax.js, because $.style is not defined, which makes me think that it doesnt use prototype but I dont understand why! I turned off jQuery in my site because I was afraid of compatibility problems and still nothing.

Anyone has an idea of why this can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of ext powermail are you using?
I tried with 1.6.4 and got very similar error to yours. And then downgraded to 1.5.7 and it started to work!

Looks like the extension odd_pm_ajax requires 1.5.x. I think with version 1.6.x powermail started to use jQuery for javascript framework.

Changelog for 1.6.0 version of powermail copied from TER:
1.6.0: jQuery validation, extJS BE Module, Scheduler, HTML templates modified!, see http://forge.typo3.org/versions/show/678 and manual

So just use version 1.5.x and ods_pm_ajax should work.
Or try to achieve the same functionality with 1.6 and jQuery.

Cheers